# How to map a range of values on a leaflet map with Shiny?

Tags: shiny, leaflet

Shiny and SO newbie here! I tried to make an app where the user can set a range of value and see the results in a map and in the table. Here I used `quakes` dataset to make a reproducible example.

The `datatable` part works fine but not the `leaflet` part which seems to show an unique marker. I know this is probably the `min_depth` input I put in the `reactive` function because the app crash when I play with. I can't figure out what to do.

### Error message

```
Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 988 or 1, not size 1000.
i Input `..1` is `obj$depth <= as.numeric(input$max_depth)`.
  143: <Anonymous>
Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 988 or 1, not size 1000.
i Input `..1` is `obj$depth <= as.numeric(input$max_depth)`.
  53: <Anonymous>
Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 988 or 1, not size 1000.
i Input `..1` is `obj$depth <= as.numeric(input$max_depth)`.
  105: <Anonymous>
```

### Shiny app code

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)


# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Quakes Test"),

    # Sidebar with numericInput for quakes depth range 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput(inputId = "min_depth", label = "Mininum depth", value = min(quakes$depth), min = min(quakes$depth), max = max(quakes$depth)),
            numericInput(inputId = "max_depth", label = "Maximum depth", value = max(quakes$depth), min = min(quakes$depth), max = max(quakes$depth))
        ),

        # Show a map
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                leafletOutput("mymap_occ", width = "98%", height = 500))
        )
    ),
    fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "prop_table"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    #filter terrains
    depth_final <- reactive({
        obj <- quakes
        if (input$min_depth != "All") {
            obj <- quakes %>% 
                filter(obj$depth >= as.numeric(input$min_depth)) %>% 
                filter(obj$depth <= as.numeric(input$max_depth))
        }
    })
    
    output$prop_table <- renderDT({
        datatable(depth_final(), extensions = 'Buttons', rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none')
        
    })
    
    observe({
        leafletProxy("mymap_occ", data = depth_final()) %>%
            removeMarker(layerId = "FOO") %>% 
            addCircleMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
                             weight= 4, opacity = 1, color = "yellow", layerId = "FOO")
    })
    
    output$mymap_occ <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(depth_final()) %>%
            fitBounds(~min(long), ~min(lat), ~max(long), ~max(lat)) %>% 
            addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group = "Vue satellite") %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLabels, group = "Vue satellite")
    })
    
    
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. The error message results from using `obj$depth` in the filter statement. Simply use `depth`. By using `obj$depth` you are referring to the `depth` in the original `obj`. While this works in the first filter it is not recommended to do so. In the second filter however you already dropped some rows, hence you got an error message as `obj$depth` refers to `depth` column in the unfiltered df.
2. Only one marker shows up because you use `layerID` instead of `group`. See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html) on the difference between the two concepts.

Try this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #filter terrains
  depth_final <- reactive({
    obj <- quakes
    if (input$min_depth != "All") {
      obj <- quakes %>% 
        filter(depth >= as.numeric(input$min_depth)) %>% 
        filter(depth <= as.numeric(input$max_depth))
    }
    obj
  })
  
  output$prop_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(depth_final(), extensions = 'Buttons', rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none')
    
  })
  
  observe({
    leafletProxy("mymap_occ", data = depth_final()) %>%
      clearGroup(group = "FOO") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
                       weight= 4, opacity = 1, color = "yellow", group = "FOO")
  })
  
  output$mymap_occ <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(depth_final()) %>%
      fitBounds(~min(long), ~min(lat), ~max(long), ~max(lat)) %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group = "Vue satellite") %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLabels, group = "Vue satellite")
  })
  
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan for your comprehensive explanation. This help me a lot!